# Looping through a mysqli result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to display a list of status updates from artists that a logged in user is following.

So far I have this:

```
#Get the list of artists that the user has liked
$q = "SELECT * FROM artist_likes WHERE user_id = '1' ";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

  #Now grab the statuses for each artist
  $status_query = "SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE artist_id = '".$row['artist_id']."' ";
  $status_result = mysqli_query($dbc,$status_query)

}
```

But i'm not sure how to loop through and display the returned status updates?

This isn't a strong point of mine, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use an inner while loop, like you iterated over the results of the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for avoiding multiple query, you can use one query like this:

```
SELECT l.*, s.* 
from artist_likes l, status_updates s
WHERE
l.artist_id = s.artist_id and
l.user_id = '1'
```

or

```
SELECT l.*, s.* 
from artist_likes l
JOIN status_updates s on (l.artist_id = s.artist_id)
WHERE
l.user_id = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it seems like a much simpler way.

Answer (score 3):

What prevented you from doing similar to what you'd already done for the first query?  Something like follows:

```
#Get the list of artists that the user has liked
$q = "SELECT * FROM artist_likes WHERE user_id = '1' ";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

  #Now grab the statuses for each artist
  $status_query = "SELECT * FROM status_updates WHERE artist_id = '".$row['artist_id']."' ";
  $status_result = mysqli_query($dbc,$status_query)

  while($status_result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($status_result)) {
    echo $status_result_row['mycol']; // This is where you know better than us
  }
}
```

Or if those two tables `artist_likes` and `status_updates` have `artist_id` in common then you could just use one query with a join. (But don't know if you are asking for that).